# I am not sure how to implement my 2D array which is

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, plot

So I am trying to implement the following equation as a 2D array in Python:

```
u[i][j+1] = u[i][j] + dt*l*(u[i-1][j] - u[i][j]).
```

This is the code I have to do this:

```
l = 0.3
n = 3
m = 100
dt = 3.0
T = 30
A = 20
t = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)
def u0(A, t, T):
    return (A/2)*(1 + np.sin((2*np.pi*t)/T))

u = np.zeros((n, m))

for j in range(m):    
    u[0][j] = u0(A,dt*j,T) 

for i in range(0, n):
    u[i][0] = 10

for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(m-1):
        u[i][j+1] = u[i][j] + dt*l*(u[i-1][j] - u[i][j])

u01 = (A/2)*(1 + np.sin((2*np.pi*t)/T))

for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(m - 1):
        plt.plot(t, u01, 'g-')
        plt.plot((j), u[1][j+1], c = 'r', marker = '_')
        plt.plot((j), u[2][j+1], c = 'b', marker = '_')
```

The plot function won't work whenever I try to get the markers to be 'r-' or 'b-' for the final two plots, this only works for the first plot so that's why I think I have done something wrong when implementing the array.

I'm just not sure how to plot 2D arrays and would like some help.

For context, this is a car following model that I'm trying to model in Python. Where u0 is the lead car, u1 the next etc. j is the time step which the nth driver checks to see what the car in front of them is doing. The function for u0 is the behaviour of the lead car and this is all that is needed in order to figure out the behaviour of the following cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `c='r'` into `c='r-'` then matplotlib tries to interpret `r-` as a colour which is why it will give an error.

I'm not 100% sure of your desired outcome but I think you can remove the loops completely for the plotting by defining `j=np.arange(m-1)`:

```
# The rest of your code remains the same

j = np.arange(m-1)

plt.plot(t, u01, 'g-')
plt.plot(j, u[1][j + 1], 'r-')
plt.plot(j, u[2][j + 1], 'b-')

plt.show()
```

Which gives me:

[image]